# How to get total details of current week?

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, xlrd, xlwt, week-number

```
for wk in sorted(out.keys()):
rec_date = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(wk, inputfp.datemode)).isocalendar()[1]#search for dates of current week
if rec_date  == datetime.date.today().isocalendar()[1]:#conditions to check current week dates
   print '\nCurrent Week Number::' ,rec_date #printing the current week number
   print 'Total Effort::',str(out[wk])   #total efforts of current week date
```

Here is the code,its adding details according to current week dates but i need sum of all hours of current week not according to this week dates

output i got:

Current Week Number:: 37
Total Effort:: 29

Current Week Number:: 37
Total Effort:: 18

Current Week Number:: 37
Total Effort:: 20

I should get output like this current week and total effort:

Current Week Number:: 37
Total Effort:: 67

Answer (score 0):

Collect all the totals by the week number in a dictionary, then print out the results at the end of your loop.

This way, you are accumulating the numbers:

```
from collections import defaultdict

results_by_week = defaultdict(int)

for wk in sorted(out.keys()):
    rec_date = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(wk,
               inputfp.datemode)).isocalendar()[1]
    if rec_date  == datetime.date.today().isocalendar()[1]:
       results_by_week[rec_date] += int(out[wk])

for weeknum, total in results_by_week.items():
    print('Week Number: {} Total Effort: {}'.format(weeknum, total))
```